# Publishing error in asp.net

Tags: c#

In local host the change is working fine ,but while published to dev server,it is not effecting.For example -commented error message is still showing in the dev server.In local host not showing.

Except web.config I copied all files and bin to the dev server.Some changes are showing correctly but some are not.Thanks

EDIT
There is a dropdownlist ,if selection changed event is not fired then error message is showing.I changed the code so that dropdownlist selection change won't take place.still in dev server  error message is showing.

Comment: You need to provide more detail.

Comment: Did you try resetting IIS and cleaning the browser cache, if the changes are specific to html/client side?

Comment: What is the full error message that you receive?